# Optimizing PHP code (trying to determine min/max/between case)

Tags: php, optimization, switch-statement

I know this code-bit does not conform very much to best coding practices, and was looking to improve it, any ideas?

```
if ($query['date_min'] != _get_date_today())
    $mode_min = true;
if ($query['date_max'] != _get_date_today())
    $mode_max = true;

if ($mode_max && $mode_min)
    $mode = "between";
elseif ($mode_max && !$mode_min)
    $mode = "max";
elseif (!$mode_max && $mode_min)
    $mode = "min";
else
    return;

if ($mode == "min" || $mode == "between") {
    $command_min = "A";
}
if ($mode == "max" || $mode == "between") {
    $command_max = "B";
}
if ($mode == "between") {
    $command = $command_min . " AND " . $command_max;
} else {
    if ($mode == "min")
        $command = $command_min;
    if ($mode == "max")
        $command = $command_max;
}

echo $command;
```

Solution:

```
$mode_min = ($query['date_min'] != _get_date_today());
$mode_max = ($query['date_max'] != _get_date_today());

if ($mode_min){
    $command_min = "A";
}
if ($mode_max) {
    $command_max = "B";
}
if ($mode_min && $mode_max) {
    $command = $command_min . " AND " . $command_max;
} else {
    if ($mode_min)
        $command = $command_min;
    if ($mode_max)
        $command = $command_max;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically your variables are undefined if the condition is not met, so I would just use:

```
$mod_min = ($query['date_min'] != _get_date_today());
$mod_max = ($query['date_max'] != _get_date_today());
```

Apart from that, why are you defining the `$mode` variable, do you need it somewhere else? If not, you can just use `$mod_min` and `$mod_max` in your last set of `if` statements.

For example:

```
if ($mode == "min" || $mode == "between")
```

seems to translate to:

```
if ($mod_min)
```

**Edit:** An edit of your last update:

```
$command_min = "A";
$command_max = "B";

if ($mode_min && $mode_max) {
    $command = $command_min . " AND " . $command_max;
}
elseif ($mode_min){
    $command = $command_min;
}
elseif ($mode_max) {
    $command = $command_max;
} else {
    return;
}
```

Comment: `($mode == "min" || $mode == "between")` was more readable, otherwise I would have to write `((!$mode_max && $mode_min) ||($mode_max && $mode_min))` am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, works perfectly, I added the solution to the question (hope that's optimized to the max, this time around :D)

Comment: @Swizzh You are missing the `return` statement in your final solution (`!$mod_min && !$mod_max`)